# selecting records that are 3 days from expiring datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

I have a table that contains a `datetime timestamp`. What I am looking for is to select records that are exactly 3 days from the 30 day expiration based on the `datetime timestamp`.

Here is what I have so far although I don't think it is correct:

```
    SELECT jobs.*,occupations.title
    FROM jobs
    LEFT JOIN occupations on occupations.id = jobs.occupation_id
    WHERE DATE_ADD(jobs.`date_created`,INTERVAL 27 DAY) = DATE(NOW())
```

Help please :)

Answer (score 5):

If `date_created` is a `DATE`, do this:

```
SELECT jobs.*,occupations.title
FROM jobs
LEFT JOIN occupations on occupations.id = jobs.occupation_id
WHERE jobs.`date_created` = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 27 DAY);
```

If `date_created` is `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` and the time part is '00:00:00', do this:

```
SELECT jobs.*,occupations.title
FROM jobs
LEFT JOIN occupations on occupations.id = jobs.occupation_id
WHERE jobs.`date_created` >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 27 DAY) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND;
```

These queries are better in terms of performance than the one in the question because the `WHERE` clauses of my queries will induce an index range scan, whereas the `WHERE` clause in the question will induce a full table scan (even if `date_created` is indexed).

If the `jobs` table does not have an index on `date_created`, then make one

```
ALTER TABLE jobs ADD INDEX (date_created);
```

Give it a Try !!